# Is there a way to get the number of tokens in an ANTLR4 parser rule?

Tags: antlr, antlr4

In ANTLR4, it seems that predicates can only be placed at the front of sub-rules in order for them to cause the sub-rule to be skipped. In my grammar, some predicates depend on a token that appears near the end of the sub-rule, with one or more rule invocations in front of it. For example:

```
date :
    {isYear(_input.LT(3).getText())}?
        month  day=INTEGER  year=INTEGER     { ... }
```

In this particular example, I know that `month` is always one single token, so it is always Token 3 that needs to be checked by `isYear()`. In general, though, I won't know the number of tokens making up a rule like `month` until runtime. Is there a way to get its token count?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in way to get the length of the rule programmatically. You could use the documentation for [`ATNState`](http://www.antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/atn/ATNState.html) in combination with the `_ATN` field in your parser to calculate all paths through a rule - if all paths through the rule contain the same number of tokens the you have calculated the exact number of tokens used by the rule.

Comment: Oh, I see the point. The parser hasn't recognized month until after it evaluates the predicate, so its length is unknowable unless all paths for month contain the same number of tokens. It would seem to be an improvement, then, if ANTLR would allow the placement of a predicate anywhere in the sub-rule (e.g. right before the token(s) used in the predicate), and fail the whole sub-rule. That assumes that _input.LT(1) always refers to the next token when used in the middle of a sub-rule.